# If I use ccDrawLine as part of a custom class, can it detect touches?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Basically, I've got a custom class that has a draw method that draws a line from point a to point b.

I'm subclassing CCSprite, so does the line then have a bounding box I can use to detect when someone touches the line?

As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, I've cobbled together this code:

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: [touch locationInView:touch.view ]];
    for (Path *path in paths) {
        CGRect pathRect = CGRectMake(path.position.x, path.position.y, path.contentSize.width, path.contentSize.height);
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(pathRect, location)) {
            CCLOG(@"Line Touched");
        }
    }
}
```

paths is a mutable array of Path objects.  I've put logs after each statement in the method, and it gets through everything but the for loop.  For some reason, it seems like it never gets into the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can.  You just have to make sure you set the rectangle the the right size, and place it at the correct origin point, which was where I was breaking it.